# NextAuth failing to redirect to custom sign in page

Tags: authentication, next.js, okta, next-auth

I'm trying to integrate okta into a Next.js internal platform for work. Okta is going to be the sole provider and the way our other apps operate is you hit the url => you are redirected to an Okta hosted page which has you sign in => you are redirected back to the original site's homepage.

What I'm struggling with though is getting that initial redirect to happen. Currently, if you type in `http://localhost:3000/` you're able to see the home page despite not being authenticated. If you update the address bar to reflect the custom sign in page then the flow I described above triggers.

This is a solved problem and I'll link all the github pages I've been pouring through but for some reason this isn't fixing it for me and I'm totally out of ideas.

[The Github page describing the problem and how various people have solved it](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4078#discussioncomment-5670537)

**[...nextauth].js**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import Okta from 'next-auth/providers/okta';

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        Okta({
            clientId: process.env.OKTA_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.OKTA_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
            issuer: process.env.OKTA_OAUTH2_ISSUER as string,
        })
    ],
    NEXTAUTH_SECRET: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET as string,
    pages: {
        signIn: "/auth/signin/"
    },
    // callbacks: { // <= https://www.jaypinion.com/blog/next-auth-custom-sign-in-page-not-redirecting/
    (supposedly this fixes it - it does not so its commented out
    //     async signIn({ email }) {
    //         return email;
    //     },
    //     async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
    //         return baseUrl;
    //     },
    // },
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

**pages/auth/Signin.tsx**

```
import { useSearchParams, useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { signIn, useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Signin() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { status } = useSession();
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (status === 'unauthenticated') {
            signIn('okta');
        } else if (status === 'authenticated') {
            router.push('/');
        }
    }, [status]);

    return <div></div>;
```

**Routes in pages/api/auth/routes.ts**

```
import AuthOptions, { authOptions } from './[...nextauth]';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';

console.log(authOptions);
const handler = NextAuth(AuthOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

I'm not sure what else I can do. There is also an option with **middleware.ts** where you export the auth object there such as

```
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";

export default withAuth({
    pages: {
        signIn: "/auth/signin",
    },
});
```

note: the folks using this method in the github page I linked are referencing a time when middleware could be used within pages directories with an underscore. At this time, Next requires you have just one middleware file that's root directory in your project. more on that [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware)

but I find that also doesn't work as it should either. if I comment out the pages property in [...nextauth] and use the middleware configuration instead it *does* redirect to the correct page however it causes an infinite loop within the useEffect. it seems each render the url has the callback url appended to the end.

Appreciate any insight anyone has! This is driving me bonkers.